# How to obtain the difference between 2 image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot

I have 2 scatter plots obtained from an experiment. The images look very similar on a naked eye. I would like to obtain the difference between these 2 images. The 2 images have :

1. Same Background
2. Line markers are yellow and blue.

I am not an expert with image processing tools in Matlab. What would be the right approach to highlight the differences in the 2 scatter plots ?

Do we need to plot the scatter plots using the same linemarkers in order to obtain the difference ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you compare the data that was used to generate the plots? Otherwise, you could save them as bitmaps (and yes, you will want to use same linemarkers, etc for this) and compare them that way.

Comment: Du you care to upload the images?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the command `imshowpair(img1,img2)` to compare between images, more help can be found at [Mathworks Compare differences between images section](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshowpair.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simple, in openCV, I would use `absDiff` which will highlight the difference very well. MatLab too have this function, while I have never used the MatLab's version before, it shouldn't differ too much from the OpenCV version.

Here's the MatLab equivalent: [imabsdiff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imabsdiff.html)

An example showing how to utilise absdiff for your case: [imabsdiff example with code](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=NoJ15jLdy7YC&pg=PT55&lpg=PT55&dq=imabsdiff+example&source=bl&ots=eq7nwCNm0x&sig=gvCUbSqCGhHqmGtZGogXxpdXOMw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A6gnU73aOon4rQf2mYCwBA&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBA)

Do comment if you need anymore help, or if that doesn't solve your problem.